# HMS: Unable to reply to comment through API

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

Trying to reply to a customer comment using the API.

Calling the reply to comment API The reply gets submitted and returns **rtnCode for success**

Getting

```
{ ret: { rtnCode: 50010003, rtnDesc: 'param error' } }
```

The API details that we use when we submit in HTTP format is as follows

```
POST /api/reviews/v1/manage/dev/reviews HTTP/1.1

Host: connect-api-dra.cloud.huawei.com

requestId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

client_id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Authorization: Bearer {Access token here}

Content-Type: application/json

Content-Length: 414

    {
    
        "lang": "en-US",
    
        "appId": "XXXXXXXX",
    
        "reviewId": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    
        "devReplyContent": "Dear, Thank you for your Wonderful feedback. We appreciate your feedback and star rating. Please feel free to reach out to us anytime if you have any questions!",
    
        "countryCode": "IN"
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-com-reviewreply-0000001162548117#section739714276488) : Language, for example, **zh_CN**. The value consists of a language code defined in ISO-639-2 and a country/region code, separated with an underscore (`_`).

[image]

So you could try to change the short line here to underscore and see if it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please can try using "lang": "en_US", instead of "lang": "en-US".[separated with an underscore (_)]

Please refer below link for more detail about the parameter.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-com-reviewreply-0000001162548117